# DateTime to Days in R and finding an average

Tags: r, date, dplyr

So I am trying to find the average temperature by day. The head of the data is below. So I am trying to find the average temperature for each Monday, Tuesday, ... and Sunday. What kind of function should I use to group all the dates and find its average temperature?

```
Date
<fctr>
AvgTemp
<dbl>

1   01/01/2013  20.72222        
2   01/02/2013  19.05556        
3   01/03/2013  23.05556        
4   01/04/2013  23.88889        
5   01/05/2013  28.38889        
6   01/06/2013  29.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `wday` function from the `lubridate` package to get the week day of each date. Before that, each date should be in the `date` class, we can do that using the `dmy` function from `lubridate`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
  mutate(WeekDay = wday(Date)) %>%
  group_by(WeekDay) %>%
  summarize(AvgTemp = mean(AvgTemp)) %>%
  ungroup()
dat2
# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   WeekDay AvgTemp
#     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1       2    23.9
# 2       3    20.7
# 3       4    28.4
# 4       6    21.1
# 5       7    29
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = " Date AvgTemp
1   01/01/2013  20.72222        
2   01/02/2013  19.05556        
3   01/03/2013  23.05556        
4   01/04/2013  23.88889        
5   01/05/2013  28.38889        
6   01/06/2013  29.00000",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```